# Add a class to an element's first child with javascript

Tags: javascript

New to js and trying to add a class to every section's first child automatically. I'm thinking something like:

```
<script>
  var element = document.getElementsByTagName('section p:first-child');
  element.classList.add('firstp');
</script>
```

but it's not producing any effect in the document. Any help?

Comment: getElementsByTagName returns an array. Use element.forEach(function(e){e.addclass...})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `getElementsByTagName` returns a collection, not an element, so you'd have to iterate over it
- To use a string, enclose the string in string delimiters, like `'`
- To use a selector string to select elements, use `querySelectorAll`. `getElementsByTagName` only accepts tag names (like `p`, or `span` - it's not flexible at all):

  ```
  var allFirstPs = document.querySelectorAll('section p:first-child');
  allFirstPs.forEach((p) => {
    p.classList.add('firstp');
  });
  ```

To support older browsers (since `NodeList.prototype.forEach` is a somewhat new method), use `Array.prototype.forEach` instead:

```
var allFirstPs = document.querySelectorAll('section p:first-child');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  allFirstPs,
  function(p) {
    p.classList.add('firstp');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `querySelectorAll` (to get the paragraphs) and `forEach` (to iterate over each paragraph) to accomplish this:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('section p:first-child');

elements.forEach((e) => {
    e.classList.add('firstp');
});
```

```css
.firstp {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <p>1st</p>
  <p>2nd</p>
  <p>3rd</p>
</section>
<section>
  <p>1st</p>
  <p>2nd</p>
  <p>3rd</p>
</section>
<section>
  <p>1st</p>
  <p>2nd</p>
  <p>3rd</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

use querySelectorAll:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('section p:first-child');
```

and iterate over result:

```
[...elements].forEach((element) => element.classList.add('firstp'));
```